# is there a method to select all categories MeSH with sparql

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, sparql, pubmed

i want to get data with sparql from Medical Subject Headings RDF

i try to do this code :

```
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX meshv: <http://id.nlm.nih.gov/mesh/vocab#>
PREFIX mesh: <http://id.nlm.nih.gov/mesh/>
PREFIX mesh2015: <http://id.nlm.nih.gov/mesh/2015/>
PREFIX mesh2016: <http://id.nlm.nih.gov/mesh/2016/>
PREFIX mesh2017: <http://id.nlm.nih.gov/mesh/2017/>

SELECT DISTINCT ?descriptor ?label
FROM <http://id.nlm.nih.gov/mesh>

WHERE {
mesh:D009369 meshv:treeNumber ?treeNum .
?childTreeNum meshv:parentTreeNumber+ ?treeNum .
?descriptor meshv:treeNumber ?childTreeNum .
?descriptor rdfs:label ?label .
}

ORDER BY ?label
```

this code return

```
 descriptor     label
mesh:D000182    ACTH Syndrome, Ectopic
mesh:D049913    ACTH-Secreting Pituitary Adenoma
mesh:D000008    Abdominal Neoplasms
```

but me i want to get from this page for example https://meshb.nlm.nih.gov/record/ui?ui=D000172 :

```
Musculoskeletal Diseases [C05]
Bone Diseases [C05.116]
Bone Diseases, Endocrine [C05.116.132]
Acromegaly [C05.116.132.082]
Congenital Hypothyroidism [C05.116.132.256]
.........
```

but i want to collect all data (code with label) from mesh,  not only this example

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm not answering your question, but you are missing the rdfs prefix in the beginning...

PREFIX rdfs: http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#

Paul