# is there a method to get data with sparql from medical MeSH data?

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, sparql, sparqlwrapper

but me i want to get from this page for example : https://meshb.nlm.nih.gov/treeView :

```
Musculoskeletal Diseases [C05]
    Bone Diseases [C05.116]
         Bone Diseases, Endocrine [C05.116.132]
               Acromegaly [C05.116.132.082]
               Congenital Hypothyroidism [C05.116.132.256]
               Dwarfism, Pituitary [C05.116.132.358]
               Gigantism [C05.116.132.479]
               Osteitis Fibrosa Cystica [C05.116.132.684]
```

I want to get with sparql in output:

```
the category             [TreeNumber]

Musculoskeletal Diseases [C05]
Bone Diseases [C05.116]
Bone Diseases, Endocrine [C05.116.132]
Acromegaly [C05.116.132.082]
Congenital Hypothyroidism [C05.116.132.256]
.....
```

So tried many code in sparql and i don't have what i want ... any ideas please ?

Comment: it's now the third question with the same topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64879704/is-there-a-method-to-select-all-categories-mesh-with-sparql and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64887803/strange-behavior-of-content-negotiation-concerning-sparql-construct-query - you guys should work together with your university assignment, clearly StackOverflow is the wrong platform for homework solutions

Comment: Also, without seeing any SPARQL query being tried, I doubt that anybody would be willing to help here